# How do I get the value of a property in my product on my phtml file?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, phtml, query

Im looking at my
`theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml`
 and I am trying to set up a conditional so that when a custom field that another developer built in as a dropdown is === 1, i want to hide the special price. How can I access these variables? Im having a very hard time dumping the productId variable to see what's in it. I keep getting blank screens

Comment: ok can you share me which variable please share me more details I can help you

Comment: you want attribute value? what is property?